# Emacs - sticking tab to frame

Tags: emacs, frame, tabbar

It has been a month that I'm using Emacs and after a lot of configuration, I really appreciate it now.
I have installed tabbar but I don't like the default behaviour which is to display all tabs in all frame.

exemple : https://i.stack.imgur.com/85wvB.png

I would like tabbar to display for exemple headers in the left frame and .cpp in the right frame, make tabs stick to only one frame.
Can tabbar be configured to do that or is there any other plugin that behaves this way ?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a single frame containing two windows. I suspect you have your "frame" and "window" terminology mixed up in your question.

Comment: @phils - you are correct, I think he has foncused terms, but the credit for that confusion is really on emacs, which uses the terms "window" and "frame" to mean the opposite of what everyone else thinks they mean.

Comment: Does anything else use the term "frame"? "Window" ended up being the common term for what Emacs had called a "frame", but I don't think the opposite is the case? (That wouldn't make any sense).

Answer (score 2):

The discussion on the Wiki page suggests that TabBar shows all tabs belonging to the same "group" as the current buffer, and that grouping rules can be customised.

> Also, emacs’s tabbar mode’s tab can be hidden, as if showing only the current “page” of a tab set, called a “group”. By default, tabs are grouped by major mode. So, for example, if current buffer is in html-mode, all the tabs shown are other buffers in html-mode. If there are no other html-mode buffers, then you will have only one tab, even if you have lots other buffers. All your dired buffers, C-mode buffers, java-buffers, etc, are in other tab group and is hidden. You have to click on a special tab widget to switch to them, or use keyboard shortcut to switch tab or tab group.
>
> What is considered as a tab group can be customized. You could set it up so every buffer is of the same group.

Custom tab group definitions sounds like a way to do what you want, assuming I've understood the question correctly.

The Wiki also has an example of some customisation.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode

Comment: Yes but they explain how to group by type of file like "emacs buffer", "user buffer"... and not by frame. But I think it is possible. Maybe using tabgroup functions to write my own configuration will provide me the solution. Thank you phils !

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode get tabbar from:

http://emhacks.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/emhacks/emhacks/tabbar.el

Most Emacs user happy without tabbar. Look [Do you use Emacs tabbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811126/do-you-use-emacs-tabbar)

For example I prefer:

```
(iswitchb-mode 1)
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore
      '("^ "
        "^\*Buffer"
        "^\*Completions\*"
        "^\*Quail Completions\*"
        "^TAGS"
        ))

(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward)

;; buffer-menu better then buffer-list, but ibuffer much better.
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'ibuffer)
```

among another buffer switching techniques.

Look also at [Tabbed windows on Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716470/tabbed-windows-on-emacs) and http://amitp.blogspot.com/2007/04/emacs-buffer-tabs.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already look to those links without sucess. They don't answer to what I am looking for. Moreover I don't really like to switch buffer using ibuffer, it is for me a waste of time when you have few files to edit. I'll look further to uniquify which I don't know, maybe it will help me ;-)

Comment: Actually uniquify doesn't do what I'm looking for. It's strange though that after all the research I've done, I can't find anyone who wants this "normal" behaviour (all the text editors that support multi-frame behaves like that normally) :-(